# Next.js context api gives me build error when I try to deploy

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-context

I want to use Context api to share some data on all pages and components on my next.js project.

I get my data from pageProps, and want to send it to my context as prop. It works on local but when I try to deploy, it shows me build error. Error doesn't come from pages but components.
How can I fix this issue?

```
context   
     import React, { useContext } from 'react';
        import {
          IGlobalConfigContextProps,
          GlobalConfigContextType,
        } from '@/config/config.types';
        
        const config = {
          canAddUser: false,
          canEditUser: false,
          canDeleteUser: false,
          canLoginLocally: false,
        };
        
        const GlobalConfigContext = React.createContext<null | GlobalConfigContextType>(
          { config }
        );
        
        export const GlobalConfigContextProvider = ({
          children,
          config,
        }: IGlobalConfigContextProps) => {
          return (
            <GlobalConfigContext.Provider value={{ config }}>
              {children}
            </GlobalConfigContext.Provider>
          );
        };
        
        export const useGlobalConfigContext = () => useContext(GlobalConfigContext);


_app.tsx
    function App({ Component, pageProps, err }: AppPropsWithLayout): JSX.Element {
      const { layoutProps, session, config, ...modifiedPageProps } =
        pageProps as IDocumentPageData;
      
      const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);
    
      return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          <GlobalConfigContextProvider config={config}>
                  {getLayout(
                    <Component {...modifiedPageProps} err={err} />,
                    modifiedPageProps
                  )}
    
                  {modifiedPageProps.serverErrors?.length > 0 &&
                    modifiedPageProps.serverErrors.map((e) => (
                      <ErrorDialog key={e.message} error={e} />
                    ))}
          </GlobalConfigContextProvider>
        </SessionProvider>
      );
    }
```